# Dúvida - Google Drive + Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, google-drive-api

Boa noite,

Seria possível usar o serviço do Google Drive 
como HOST do SQLite?

Obrigado!

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada sobre Google Drive REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resposta curta:

Não.

### Resposta menos curta:

Hipoteticamente, daria para você instalar um *driver* que montasse o google drive como sendo um dispositivo real, com um *filesystem* similar aos do OS em uso, o que tornaria o acesso de arquivos transparente para a aplicação.

Entretanto, ficaria um processo tão mais lento que um FS local, que tornaria seu uso prático inviável.

Comment: Entendo. Muito obrigado!